# scala parameterised merge sort - confusing error message

Tags: scala, sorting, mergesort

I am getting a compilation error when calling the **(lt: (T,T) => Boolean) function**
The error code is *"type mismatch; found : x.type (with underlying type T) required: T"*
and the x parameter in *lt(**x**,y)* is underlined.

```
object sort {
  def msort[T](xs: List[T])(lt: (T, T) => Boolean): List[T] = {
    def merge[T](xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] = (xs, ys) match {
      case (Nil, ys) => ys
      case (xs, Nil) => xs
      case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) => {
        if (lt(x, y)) x :: merge(xs1, ys)
        else y :: merge(xs, ys1)
      }
    }

    val n = xs.length / 2
    if (n == 0) xs
    else {
      val (left, right) = xs splitAt n
      merge(msort(left)(lt), msort(right)(lt))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`msort` and `merge` have different type parameters. Remove the `T` type parameter from `merge`:

```
def merge(xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] = (xs, ys) match {
```

The `[T]` declares a new parameter unrelated to the first. You get the same error if you declare it as:

```
def merge[U](xs: List[U], ys: List[U]): List[U] = (xs, ys) match {
```

`lt` has a type `(U, U) => Boolean`, and you're calling it with `x` and `y` which have type `T` and don't match.

Comment: Thank you this solves the problem :) . But I don't understand why? :(

Comment: @Amitai The `[T]` declares a new parameter unrelated to the first. You get the same error if you declare it as `def merge[U](xs: List[U], ys: List[U]): List[U] = (xs, ys) match {`